# JavaScript not returning int ..at least not when I think it should be

Tags: javascript

Assuming that `arr` is an array of objects.

```
arr = // some items;

function findItem( source, item ) {
  return source.indexOf(item);
}
```

Now, I know the code is correct, it actually does find the right index, but I get an '`undefined`' response. However if I do this..

```
function findItem( source, item ) {
  var i = 0;
  i = source.indexOf(item);
  return i;
}
```

I get the right index.

I've even tried.

```
function findItem(source, item) {
 return parseInt( source.indexOf(item) );
}
```

and I still get an '`undefined`'.

Can someone tell me what in the world is going on?

### Okay, to make things a bit simpler, I'll post more code here.

```
        function init() {
            alert(discoverWithoutVar());
            alert(discoverWithVar());
        }
        function discoverWithoutVar() {
            var arr = [{ Name: "Stacey" }, { Name: "Ciel" }, { Name: "Derek" }, { Name: "Christi"}];

            // find the index of 'Ciel'
            arrayForEach(arr, function (e) {
                if (e.Name == "Ciel") {
                    return arrayIndexOf(arr, e);
                }
            });
        }
        function discoverWithVar() {
            var arr = [{ Name: "Stacey" }, { Name: "Ciel" }, { Name: "Derek" }, { Name: "Christi"}];

            var i = 0;
            // find the index of 'Ciel'
            arrayForEach(arr, function (e) {
                if (e.Name == "Ciel") {
                    i = arrayIndexOf(arr, e);
                }
            });

            return i;
        }
        function arrayForEach(array, action) {
            for (var i = 0, j = array.length; i < j; i++)
                action(array[i]);
        }

        function arrayIndexOf(array, item) {
            if (typeof array.indexOf == "function")
                return array.indexOf(item);
            for (var i = 0, j = array.length; i < j; i++)
                if (array[i] == item)
                    return i;
            return -1;
        }
```

Comment: JavaScript does not have an `int` keyword or type (only `Number`), so there's no way the second works.  On the other hand, the first will work fine (see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/guZCD/)) in a ECMAScript-5 compliant browser (not IE).  What are you using to run this?

Comment: running it in my chrome JS debugger, with source being ["a", "b", "c"] and item being any of those, it works fine. It DOES return an item of type 'number' though, not int

Comment: Are you sure this is all of the code? `indexOf` should never return `undefined`.

Comment: I meant 'var' instead of int.

Comment: Then there's effectively no difference between the first and second.  And you still haven't said what you're testing in.

Comment: What 'source' is is irrelevant. The point is that adding the var i = 0 makes it return something, but otherwise it returns undefined. But in this case, 'source' is a JSON array. [{Name:"Person1"},{Name:"Person2"}].

Comment: I'm testing in Google Chrome and FireFox and IE8.

Comment: Ok, what is the 'item' you are searching for? {Name: "Person1"} or "Person1" or Name.Person1 or something else?

Comment: Well it isn't about the data. It does this with a myriad of any arrays I use of any type. I walk through the debugger in Chrome and it ALWAYS finds the item right, it just RETURNS undefined unless I ASSIGN it to a variable.

Comment: Let me update it with more clear code, since this is beyond the scope of the data I was showing it seems.

Comment: Okay, I've added some code with more functions that might make it more clear. The fact that using the var would get the right answer made me assume it couldn't be an issue with the sub-functions. But those are what it is using to do the searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why you should post real code you've tested with.  If you want to simplify, make it is as simple as you can *while* still showing the problem.  Then post that.

```
    function discoverWithoutVar() {
        var arr = [{ Name: "Stacey" }, { Name: "Ciel" }, { Name: "Derek" }, { Name: "Christi"}];

        // find the index of 'Ciel'
        arrayForEach(arr, function (e) {
            if (e.Name == "Ciel") {
                return arrayIndexOf(arr, e);
            }
        });
    }
```

is wrong, because you're just returning from the anonymous function you pass to the for each (not from `discoverWithoutVar`).

```
function arrayForEach(array, action) {
    for (var i = 0, j = array.length; i < j; i++)
        action(array[i]); // The value you return is being discarded here
}
```

Just use a regular for loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
  if (arr[i].Name == "Ciel") {
    return arrayIndexOf(arr, e);
  }
}
```

The reason the `var i` makes it work is that `i` is being closed into the anonymous function.  Then, you're setting it inside, but returning from the outer function.  If the `var i`, `i =`, and return were all in the anonymous function, it would indeed make no difference.

Comment: Beat me to it. I guess that's what I get for being on Hulu at the same time.

Comment: @josh - was Hulu mad or just squished?

Answer (score 3):

Just to prove I wasn't lying about it working, a screenshot of the debugger.
I would advise you take a very close look at what you are passing for your variables.

[image]

Like Matthew said, you discard the value. Adding a return on arrayForEach would return the value found by your functions.

Comment: Alright, I've added some extra code to show more of what it is doing. The fact that using a var would still get me the result, I really didn't think there could be a problem with the other functions (since it is obviously finding the right thing each time)

Comment: And I never suspected you were lying, I just tried to give the code that I felt was relevant to the problem. I've been down voted before for giving 'too much code' when it was deemed 'unnecessary' and I try to avoid that by only posting what I feel is relevant.

Comment: It's good, thanks for posting more code in a case like this it's good to see what you are doing. Giving us the functions proved helpful (see @Matthew)